# gRPC server segfault when going out of scope

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

with the following code, I managed to cause a segfault on the server when the client call a server's method.

```
std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server;
{
    grpc::ServerBuilder server_builder;
    server_builder.AddListeningPort("localhost:4500", grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    MyServiceImpl service;
    server_builder.RegisterService(&service);
    server = server_builder.BuildAndStart();
}
server->Wait();
```

But if I move `server->Wait();` inside the curly bracket, every thing works as expected.

Is this the expected behaviour? As in, it is designed to be like so?

Comment: What is `server`? Are there typos for `server_`? Do `server_builder` or `service` need to live past the `server =` line?

Comment: Lifetime issue https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server_builder.html#a4f62f6efaa8d47ffbcffc314cff6b1e4

Comment: @Passerby Yes, it's a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Passerby so the problem here is because my service died because it went of of scope, while my server is alive?

Comment: The docs say that the service must exist for the lifetime of the server instance, so try moving the service above the block.

Comment: @Passerby This solved the problem. Thanks!